# Neural Neworks - Different learning rate for each weight

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, learning-rate

I have few questions regarding the theory behind neural networks' gradient descent.

First question: Lets say we have 5 weights one for each of the 5 features. And now we want to compute the gradient. How does the algorithm internally do it? Does it take the first weight (=W1) and tries increasing it a bit (or decreasing it) and when it is done, goes to the 2nd weight? Or does it do it differently and more efficiently by changing simultaneously more than 1 weights?

Second question: If feature 1 is way way more important that feature 2, so the same change (in %) of W1 has a bigger effect on loss compared to W2, isn't it better to have a different learning rate for each weight? If we have only one learning rate, we set it by taking account only the most impactful weight, right?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1:

It just does gradient descent. You don't wiggle weights independently: you stack your weights in a vector/matrix/tensor `W` an compute and increment `delta_W` which itself is a (respectively) vector/matrix/tensor. Once you know this increment you apply it to all weights at once.

For question 2:

There are already many algorithms that tune the learning rate to parameters. See for example [RMSprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#RMSProp) and [Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#RMSProp). Those are usually (roughly said) based on the frequency at which a parameter intervenes.

Regarding the "importance" that you describe:

> so the same change (in %) of W1 has a bigger effect on loss compared to W2, isn't it better to have a different learning rate for each weight

You are just describing gradient! In that case `W1` has a higher gradient than `W2`, and it already is being updated with a higher weight, so to speak. It wouldn't make much sense though to play around with its learning rate independently unless you have more information about its role (*e.g.* the frequency mentinoed above).